# how to properly send ssis package to another user to deploy

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I developed an SSIS package which runs fine i VS. To deploy the package, I need to send it to the DBA to deploy on the server but am getting login errors. I've narrowed it down to (what I believe is causing the issue) is the "ProtectionLevel: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" setting.

so when the dba opens the visual studio project, he doesnt get the passwords because of the settings and then running the dtsx files fails on the servers.

How do I properly send in the project so he can deploy it without re-typing in the passwords?

Comment: Exactly what error message did you get ?

Comment: M.Ali I'm getting "DTS:Password....Key not valid for use in specified state. You may not be authorized to access this information"

Comment: What kind of database logins do you use? Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication? I find it simplest to use windows authentication and use DontSaveSensitive. You should read about protections levels and understand them.

Comment: using sql authentication...cant use windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/01/12/understanding-the-ssis-package-protection-level.aspx

It sounds like Server Storage or Dont Save Sensitive with a configuration package is the way to go for your scenario.

Another option is to store the connection strings that require the passwords as string variables and hard-code the values.  This is a pain when you need to change the password, however.

Comment: If I do "dont save sensitive".....then all passwords have to be put back in once deployed to the server, right?

Comment: The passwords should be contained in the configuration file.  Then the package configure to load the config file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SSIS ProtectionLevel (property of the package) to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword.  This will force you to add a new password to the package.  Your dba will be prompted for this package password when the package is opened.  Without the password, access to the sensitive data (i.e. connection passwords within package) will not be possible.